# Appcelerator/Javascript Using Variable as Routine Syntax Question

Tags: javascript, appcelerator

Really a javascript question, but here's my code........I would truly appreciate some help.  Been too long since I've been in the coding trenches.  Here's my code.

I want to make loadtravelurl into a single function I can call from multiple places.

These three lines below are my issues.
win2.title = title;
win2.add(tv);
tab2.open(webwin);

I want to be able to pass variables in loadelectronicsurl function, where I can change the text win2 in win2.title and win2.add(tv) dynamically.  Also want to do the same with tab2.  I know it can be done, just had a few years off and forgot how to do so in javascript.

Here is the full code, thanks so much for the help in advance!

```
function loadelectronicsurl(){
var WindowWidth = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth; 
var WindowHeight = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.open('GET',electronicsurl);
var data = [];
var WindowWidth = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;

    xhr.onload = function() {
        //Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
        var xml = this.responseXML;
        var channel = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("channel");
        var title = channel.item(0).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text;
        win2.title = title;
        var items = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
            var this_post_title = items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text;
            var post_link = items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("link").item(0).text;
            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:'auto',width:WindowWidth,top:0,hasChild: false});
            var post_title = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                text: this_post_title,
                textAlign:'left',
                left:0,
                height:40,
                font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontSize:12},
                width:'auto',
                top:3,
                color: 'black'
            }); 
            row.add(post_title);
            row.link = post_link;
            data.push(row);         
        }
        var tv = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
            data:data,
            top:0,
            width:WindowWidth,
            height:WindowHeight
        });
        win2.add(tv);
        tv.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
            var webwin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                url: 'showweb.js',
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                myurl: e.rowData.link
            });
            tab2.open(webwin);
        });
    };

    xhr.send();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define parameters for a function like this:

```
function someFunc(win, tab){

    win.add();
    tab.open();

}
```

You can also use the parameters to access properties of an object dynamically like this:

```
function someFunc(win, tab){

    obj.[win](); //To call an object's method
    obj.[tab]; //To access an object's property

}
```

Call the function and pass the paramters:

```
someFunc(someObject, anotherObject);
```

`someObject` becomes `win` and `anotherObject` becomes `tab` inside the function.